# Add column to different worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want to add a dynamic column into a different workbook.

Say I'm working in 1st Excel file and I want to add a column in 2nd Excel file.

My code is adding the column into the 1st Excel file.

```
Sub insertColumn()
Range("B1").EntireColumn.Insert
End Sub
```

I also tried using

```
Woorkbook("newfile.xls").Worksheets("sheet1"). Range("B1").EntireColumn.Insert
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

other then the typo (use `Workbooks` instead of `Woorkbook`) you also make sure that the name and extension of your file is correct

for instance it may be "newfile.xls" or "newfile.xlsx" or "newfile.xlsm"

if you know only have one excel file open whose name is "newfile" then you can omit the extension

```
Workbooks("newfile").Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B1").EntireColumn.Insert
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the command to

```
Columns("B:B").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
```

or

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A:A").Insert
```

And check the correct parameters Shift and copyorigin